# Show that if a,b are natural numbers then a+b is a natural number.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I would like to use a case by case basis to show that for all $a,b \in \mathbb{N}, a+b \in \mathbb{N}$. I point out that there are two types of elements in $\mathbb{N}$ $$2k$$ and $$2k+1$$ (I think this could be the problem since this argument does not include $1$) and go through each different pairing. I run into a problem right away when pairing two even numbers (even plus odd does have the same problem). Here is what I did: Let $a=2m$ and let $b=2n \implies a+b = 2m + 2n = 2(m+n)$. Let $m+n = k \implies a+b = 2k  $ and $2k\in \mathbb{N}$. I know that $(m+n)$ is an integer is what I am trying to prove. So my proof is essentially relying on the thing I am trying to prove. Is there a better elementary way to show that $\mathbb{N}$ is closed under addition or is it that we just take it as an axiom?

Comment: Since you are trying to prove something so *fundamental* (we usually just assume it is true), I think it is important to have a definition of *"natural number"*. What does it mean for $a$ and $b$ to be natural numbers?

Comment: All numbers of the form $1$ or $n+1$ for $n$ a positive non-zero integer.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but isn't it precisely how $\mathbb{N}$ is defined? Using Peano axioms, you can say that $0$ is a natural number, that every natural number has a successor, and that $0$ is the successor of no natural number.

Comment: We need also to define addition formally, perhaps in terms of successor. Then we can proceed by induction on $b$. $a+1$ is a natural number, and by definition $a+(b+1)=(a+b)+1$, so if $a+b$ is a natural number then so is $(a+b)+1$, and therefore $a+(b+1)$.

Comment: @JefferyDittenber, Then how do we define an *integer*?

Answer (score 1):

Do a Google search for
"landau foundations of analysis"
and here is the first hit:

[http://www.amazon.com/Foundations-Analysis-AMS-Chelsea-Publishing/dp/082182693X](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/082182693X)

Foundations of Analysis (AMS Chelsea Publishing ...
www.amazon.com/Foundations-Analysis.../08218269...
Amazon.com, Inc.
 Rating: 4.5 - ‎14 reviews
Foundations of Analysis (AMS Chelsea Publishing) [Edmund Landau] on Amazon.com. *FREE* shipping on qualifying offers. Why does $2 \times 2 = 4$?

This book does exactly what you want:
Defines the natural numbers,
then addition,
then...